# React & Meteor componentDidMount Explanation

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

Following the meteor react todo tutorial,

I was confused on the following lines of code, could somebody explain what is happening here as I feel this will need to be used a lot when using other packages.

```
// we create the account ui component
AccountsUIWrapper = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    // use meteor blaze to render the login buttons
    this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
  },
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // clean up blaze view
    Blaze.remove(this.view);
  },
  render() {
    return <span ref="container" />;
  }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking specifically what componenetDidMount and what componentWillUnmount do? If so have you looked at the lifecycle methods from the react docs? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: No, at least I don't think so, sorry I'm new to this.  It's more of a question of how does the account-ui get rendered when we are returning just <span ref=container />

Comment: Understood - wrote an answer based off of your comment - let me know if that helps your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of your most recent comment, seems like the confusion lies with the render function only containing `<span ref=container />`. I'm not familiar with Meteor/Blaze but I can give an educated enough answer based off of react. Essentially what is happening is after the initial render, componentDidMount is being called. There you have:

```
Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
React.findDOMNode(this.refs.container))
```

Which is appending/rendering the loginButtons on that `<span ref=container>` (React.findDOMNode(this.refs.container) will return the node referenced by the this.refs).

Comment: So just so I get this, if I changed the ref attribute to login I would need to change this.refs.container to this.refs.login in order for me to render the login buttons

Comment: Correct - this.refs is a property you can define for each react Component Class that contains an array of all 'reffed' jsx elements. These can be labeled anything as long as it is unique within that class (ie you can't have two refs called login in a component class or they'd conflict). So if I were to change that span to have the prop ref='login' - if I wanted to render something on it using Blaze.render, the second argument would need to be React.findDOMNode(this.refs.login) - which will give Blaze the actual DOM node. Read more at: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html